# Edit a custom field in netsuite using PHP toolkit

Tags: php, netsuite

I see a bunch of examples of how to add a new order however I'm trying to update a custom field of an existing order using the PHP toolkit. Could anyone start me out with this? I'm not sure where to start.

This is the code to add a new order

```
<?php

require_once '../PHPToolkit/NetSuiteService.php';

$service = new NetSuiteService();

$svr = new getSelectValueRequest();
$svr->fieldDescription = new GetSelectValueFieldDescription();
$svr->pageIndex = 1;

$priceFields = array(
    'recordType'  => RecordType::salesOrder,
    'sublist'    => 'itemList',
    'field'    => 'price',
    'filterByValueList'    => array(
        'filterBy'    => array(
            array(
            'field'    => 'item',
            'sublist'    => 'itemList',
            'internalId'        => '458',
        )
            )
    )
);


if ($id != null) {
    echo "Custom price level id is " . $id . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Custom price level not found " . $id . "\n";
}

$so = new SalesOrder();
$so->entity = new RecordRef();
$so->entity->internalId = 21;
$so->itemList = new SalesOrderItemList();
$soi = new SalesOrderItem();
$soi->item = new RecordRef();
$soi->item->internalId = 104;
$soi->quantity = 3;
$soi->price = new RecordRef();
$soi->price->internalId = $id;
$soi->amount = 55.3;
$so->itemList->item = array($soi);

$request = new AddRequest();
$request->record = $so;

$addResponse = $service->add($request);

if (!$addResponse->writeResponse->status->isSuccess) {
    echo "ADD ERROR";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "ADD SUCCESS, id " . $addResponse->writeResponse->baseRef->internalId;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a customFieldList object, which is an array of custom fields. There are different objects for the different data types of custom fields - below would be a string custom field. I utf8_encode to deal with weird characters that you normally don't see.

```
$customFieldList = new CustomFieldList();
$customField = new StringCustomFieldRef();
$customField->value = utf8_encode("contents of string custom field");
$customField->internalId = 'custbody_whatever_your_field_is';
$customFieldList->customField[] = $customField;

$so->customFieldList = $customFieldList;
```

Comment: thanks, how do I select the specific order from netsuite that I want to update?

Comment: this is what i have, http://pastebin.com/Z54z4AZT     is that id 21 the order id that I want to change?

Comment: set the internalid on the sales order.

$so->internalid = 1234;

Comment: thanks for the help. i'm getting an INVALID_KEY_OR_REF, The specified key is invalid. In the response back. This is my code. http://pastebin.com/1dkQUJzp , 2074 is the order # and 229 is the internal id of my custom transaction body field. any ideas why it isn't working?

Comment: Is 2074 the internal ID of the order, or the number that is visible to the end user? Pull up the record in the UI - the internal ID is the number at the end of the URL.

Comment: Is there any option to create new custom item field for inventory item ?